# josso integration with spring web srevices

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-ws, josso

I require help on integration of web service with JOSSO for authentication.
Whenever a request comes from SOAP UI(client) to service, it should be authenticated against an Active Directory server, and if it succeeds then it should hit the service endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long struggle, we came to know JOSSO exposing their login methods as web services also.
But for authenticating against AD, you have to make least two or three web service calls.

1. Get Assertion Id by passing Username & Password.
2. Get Session Id by passing Assertion Id.
3. Get Role information by passing the Session Id.

Just for testing, you can download this wsdl as a project in to SOAP-UI tool and hit to get response.

[JOSSO WEB SERVICES WSDL LINK](http://www.josso.org/wsdl/josso-1.2/josso-1.2.wsdl)

You can find the same from source code also:
 \josso-1.8.3-src\components\josso-ws-v1_2\src\main\wsdl\josso-1.2.wsdl